# Why load operation in BigQuery is not being charged?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform, cost-management

When I loaded data into BigQuery using google API (golang),
I could check the costs of streaming insertion (like streaming insert ~$5.54).

Then I tried to load data into BigQuery using Embulk (csv file, compressed by gzip) but I couldn't check the costs about data loaded.

Can anyone explain about this problem?

- streaming data (json) = 30GB
- gz datasize = 8~15GB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not actually a problem but more like a feature of BigQuery. As you can see in the [pricing table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing) for BQ, [load operations](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/loading-data) are free of charge (you should only keep in mind the [quotas](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quota-policy#import) for this job)

Load operations are operations such as bringing data from Google Cloud Storage or BigTable directly to BigQuery, or also the Media Upload where you send the contents of your file as media content in the `http` request to BQ.

Those operations are free of charge.

As for live streaming, as you can see in the table, currently we are charged $0.05 per GB streamed.